# Prolog-Multiplying a list with a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog, multiplication

I'm trying to simulate a product of a matrix with a vector using these two predicates:

```
eva([], [], []).
eva([A|A1], [W], [Res|R1]) :-
    vectormultiplication(A, W, Res),
    eva(A1, W, R1).

vectormultiplication([A], [W], [A*W]).
vectormultiplication([A|A1], [W|W1], [A*W|Out1]) :-
    vectormultiplication(A1, W1, Out1).
```

Where the `[A|A1]` in eva is a matrix (or a list of lists), `[W]` is a vector (a list),and `[Res|R1]` is the resulting product. `vectormultiplication` is supposed to go multiply each list in the list with the vector `W`.  However, this strategy just produces a false response.  Is there anything apparent that I'm doing wrong here that prevents me from getting the desired product? I'm currently using SWI Prolog version 5.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 other problems apart that evidenced by Daniel (+1): here a cleaned up source

```
eva([], _, []).  % here [] was wrong
eva([A|A1], W, [Res|R1]) :- % here [W] was wrong
    vectormultiplication(A, W, Res),
    eva(A1, W, R1).

vectormultiplication([A], [W], [M]) :-
    M is A*W.
vectormultiplication([A|A1], [W|W1], [M|Out1]) :-
    M is A*W,
    vectormultiplication(A1, W1, Out1).
```

test:

```
?- eva([[1,2],[3,5]],[5,6],R).
R = [[5, 12], [15, 30]]
```

when handling lists, it's worth to use [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29) if available

```
eva(A, W, R) :-
    maplist(vectormultiplication1(W), A, R).

vectormultiplication1(W, A, M) :-
    maplist(mult, A, W, M).

mult(A, W, M) :-
    M is A*W.
```

Note I changed the order of arguments of vectormultiplication1, because the vector is a 'constant' in that loop, and maplist append arguments to be 'unrolled'.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your first problem is that you think `A*W` is going to do anything by itself. In Prolog, that's just going to create the expression `A*W`, no different from `*(A,W)` or `foo(A, W)`--without `is/2` involved, no actual arithmetic reduction will take place. That's the only real problem I see in a quick glance.

Comment: Okay, so I could create another predicate to handle that multiplication aspect?

Comment: @CapelliC has illustrated all that needs to be done, I didn't catch all the problems in my quick read.